# What is the use of Dart RawSockets?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, dart, flutter

I mean, I've read questions about Dart RawSockets and also read the API but it was not clear for me to understand how to use them. Are Dart RawSockets the same as C rawsockets?

Also, what is the difference between Dart RawSockets and normal Sockets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Socket` is a higher level concept. It implements a `Stream` of bytes (actually byte arrays) and an `IOSink`. `listen` to the stream and data arriving at the socket appears in the stream. When you want to send data down the socket, `add` it to the sink and away it goes.

A `RawSocket` is the lower level concept. Now, instead of getting a stream of bytes, you are just told when bytes are available to be read. (You get a stream of events telling you when data is available. You are responsible for then calling `read` to collect them.) This allows you to work more in the mode of a Unix socket where you use `select` to know that there is data available so that you don't block when trying to read it.

Dart's streams relieve you of much of the responsibility of select/blocking read/separate reader thread of different languages. When reading from a `Socket` you don't need to worry, data just arrives in the stream when it's available.

Note how there is only a `RawDatagramSocket`. This makes sense, since UDP packets are discrete, not a byte stream. A UDP socket just tells you that a packet is available to be read, and you then read it.

Comment: Thanks for answer! But its not clear to me yet if the RawSocket of Dart is the same as the C RawSocket, is it?

Comment: No, quite different. Dart's `RawSocket` is most definitely a TCP socket, just like Dart's `Socket`.